# mypy error: Cannot instantiate abstract class with abstract attributes when adding types to an abstract method

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a class I would like to add typehints to that looks as following:

```
import yaml

class TestClass(dict):

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, fname) -> "TestClass":
        return cls(yaml.safe_load(""))

    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def test(self):
        raise
```

when I run mypy on a module containing only this class I get the following error message:

```
error: Cannot instantiate abstract class 'TestClass' with abstract attribute 'test'
```

From what I have understood from other posts this has something to do with when the 'test' method is instantiated when executing the load method. Is there a way to fix this issue using typehints alone or would I need to adjust my code here?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? It doesn't make much sense using ``abc.abstractmethod`` on a class that is not an ``abc.ABC``.

Answer (score 0):

What mypy is telling you is that `TestClass.load(...)` will fail, because it will try to create an instance of the abstract class `TestClass`.

We can fix this by requiring that `cls` can be called with whatever `yaml.safe_load` returns (I'm assuming `dict` here), and returns an instance of `TestClass`:

```
from typing import Callable
import abc
import yaml

class TestClass(dict):

    @classmethod
    def load(cls: Callable[[dict], TestClass], fname) -> "TestClass":
        return cls(yaml.safe_load(""))

    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def test(self):
        raise
```

Note that `TestClass.load("foo")` will now also pass type checking. This is fair to some extent, because it's also fine at runtime, until you call `test()` on the created instance. I think this might be a limitation of how mypy implements protocols.

Comment: ``def load(cls: Any, fname)`` should do the same as ``cast``ing in this case.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi can you explain more clearly why this error occurs? When return cls(yaml.safe_load("") is called we instantiate the class with the dictionary returned by yaml, but how exactly does that correlate with the abstract method? Why is this problem solved by instantiating cls beforehand?

Comment: @Thomas do you maybe have an explanation? I don't quite understand why it causes a problem to just return an instance of the class with the abstract method

Comment: @hhhh Do you know what an abstract class is?

Comment: @Thomas It's like a superclass with methods that are used across different subclasses as far as I understood

Comment: Any superclass can play that role. What makes it _abstract_ is that you cannot create an instance of the superclass itself. You can only instantiate its concrete (= non-abstract) subclasses. And because `TestClass` has an `abstractmethod`, mypy infers that `TestClass` is meant to be abstract, and refuses to let you instantiate it.